# Code completion Clion

Tags: clion, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm working with Clion to write C++ code for ROS. I just started with a simple publisher which publishes a message of the type

```
geometry_msgs::Pose msg;
```

When I want to do code completion, Clion tells me 'No suggestions for members of geometry_msgs::Pose. It also tells me, that

```
#include "geometry_msgs/Pose.h"
```

is not found. The code compiles and works fine though. How can I get the code completion for a easier code writing working?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321312/code-completion-clion/) by [steradiant](https://answers.ros.org/users/40427/steradiant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2019-04-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Carl D](https://answers.ros.org/users/36816/carl-d/) on 2019-04-17**:
Did you try sourcing devel/setup.bash before launching CLion? ie. Run `source devel/setup.bash` and then from the same terminal run `clion.sh`

**Comment by [steradiant](https://answers.ros.org/users/40427/steradiant/) on 2019-04-18**:
Yes, I've tried that but it didn't work.

**Comment by [Isha Dijcks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38758/isha-dijcks/) on 2019-04-18**:
Did you go to the CMake tab in the bottom and press reload?

**Comment by [steradiant](https://answers.ros.org/users/40427/steradiant/) on 2019-04-18**:
Thanks! Seems to work now

**Comment by [Isha Dijcks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38758/isha-dijcks/) on 2019-04-18**:
If your problem is solved now, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure to reload the top-level CMake by right-clicking the file and press 'reload'. Or go to the CMake tab at the bottom and press 'reload'.

If you have more questions about setting up CLion with ROS, you can check this answer:
https://answers.ros.org/question/284786/setup-clion-with-ros/

---

Originally posted by [Isha Dijcks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38758/isha-dijcks/) with karma: 85 on 2019-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1